# HTML element not parsing correctly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning JS and trying to do a an api call to themoviedb. The spec is requiring that once a movie title is clicked, more detail about that movie is appended to the page. I am assigning the #theID to a var id and tring to concatenate the string when doing a get request, but it keep getting an error. Heres the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>URDB!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">hello world</div>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script id="All" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="List">
    <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
    <p>{{ release_date }}</p>
    <p>{{ vote_average }}</p>
    <p id="theID">{{ id }}</p>
    <h2><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w396{{poster_path}}"></h2>
  </div>
</script>
<script id="single" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="Single">
    <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
    <p>Release Date: {{ release_date }}</p>
    <p>Vote Average: {{ vote_average }}</p>
    <p>Imdb: {{ imdb_id }}</p>
    <p>Tagline: {{ tagline }}</p>
    <h2><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w396{{poster_path}}"></h2>
  </div>
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var source = $("#All").html();
  var source2 = $("#single").html();

  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var template2 = Handlebars.compile(source2);
  var myList = [];

    $.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=caa1990e26f7dab9052573323febcbdc', function(data){

    data.results.forEach(function(x){
      myList.push(x);
      var myNewHTML = template({
      title: x.title,
      release_date: x.release_date,
      vote_average: x.vote_average,
      poster_path: x.poster_path,
      id: x.id
      });

      var id = document.getElementById("#theID");
      console.log(id);
      $('body').append(myNewHTML);
      })
    });
   $("body").on('click', 'h4', function(){
   $.get('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+id+'?api_key=caa1990e26f7dab9052573323febcbdc', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var anotherHTML = template2({
        title: data.title,
        release_date: data.release_date,
        vote_average: data.vote_average,
        poster_path: data.poster_path,
        imdb_id: data.imdb_id,
        tagline: data.tagline
        });
        $('body').append(anotherHTML);
    })
   })
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you not specify theID element in html

Answer (score 0):

Use this, you don't need # for for referencing dom elements with ids in javascript.

`var id = document.getElementById("theID")`;

Comment: thanks but it is still saying var id is undefined when trying to .onclick

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the id of the html element:

```
 var id = document.getElementById("theID").id;
```

and if you want the text of the element:

```
 var id = document.getElementById("theID").innerHTML;
```