# JSON to HTML output using TMDB API

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I am using the fetch API to grab data from TMBD which I can display in the console like this...

```
fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/778?api_key=1234&append_to_response=videos,credits')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
        console.log('Output: ', out);
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The JSON looks like this...

```
{
"backdrop_path": "/8gSU1tLLdE5TWbcg9YDnR2lD0sO.jpg",
"belongs_to_collection": null,
"budget": 0,
"genres": [
    {
        "id": 99,
        "name": "Documentary"
    }
],
"homepage": "https://www.focusfeatures.com/roadrunner",
"id": 642732,
"imdb_id": "tt14512538",
"original_language": "en",
"original_title": "Roadrunner: A Film About Anthony Bourdain",
"overview": "An intimate, behind-the-scenes look at how an anonymous chef became a world-renowned cultural icon.",
"production_countries": [
    {
        "iso_3166_1": "US",
        "name": "United States of America"
    }
]
```

}

I now need to drop this into some simple HTML.
For example, some variables that are named 'original_title' and 'overview', each in their own div...

```
<div>title outputs here</div>
<div>overview outputs here</div>
```

I know this is very simple, but I can't get the JS to work.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: that is what I am trying to get help with.
json is being pulled in, and now I need to display it as html.

Comment: Would you show the json?
And can you set the id for each div?

Comment: updated with some sample json output. basically i am building a page which shows details of a movie - title, overview, cast etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199932/html-element-not-parsing-correctly-in-javascript
Check this

Comment: I need a simple way to do yhis with vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample code for your reference.

```js
let out={
  "adult": false,
  "backdrop_path": "/fCayJrkfRaCRCTh8GqN30f8oyQF.jpg",
  "belongs_to_collection": null,
  "budget": 63000000,
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 18,
      "name": "Drama"
    }
  ],
  "homepage": "",
  "id": 550,
  "imdb_id": "tt0137523",
  "original_language": "en",
  "original_title": "Fight Club",
  "overview": "A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking new form of therapy. Their concept catches on, with underground \"fight clubs\" forming in every town, until an eccentric gets in the way and ignites an out-of-control spiral toward oblivion.",
  "popularity": 0.5,
  "poster_path": null
};

function go(){
  let overViewDiv=document.getElementById("overViewDiv");
  let originalTitleDiv=document.getElementById("originalTitleDiv");
  
  overViewDiv.innerHTML=out.overview;
  originalTitleDiv.innerHTML=out.original_title;
}
```

```html
Over View:
<div id="overViewDiv"></div>
Original Title:
<div id="originalTitleDiv"></div>
<button onclick="go()">Go</button>
```

In your case,

1. Set the id for each div as the sample code.
2. And replace :

   ```
    console.log('Output: ', out);
   ```

   with :

   ```
      let overViewDiv=document.getElementById("overViewDiv");
      let originalTitleDiv=document.getElementById("originalTitleDiv");

      overViewDiv.innerHTML=out.overview;
      originalTitleDiv.innerHTML=out.original_title;
   ```

Comment: I think this overcomplicates things. I don't need buttons to trigger anything. Just a simple api fetch request to show some data in a div. I imagine it is very simple, but maybe it isn't?

Comment: I just need to replace the above console log code with something that shows a result in a div instead of logging it.

Comment: I have updated my solution, please check.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much. One additional question. How do a target a child value in the JSON? This is good for top level responses, but what about a second level - in my example JSON above - targeting the PRODUCTION COUNTRIES > NAME.

Comment: out.production_countries[0].name